# Pip package won't run if I do not use sudo while installing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, pip, packaging

So I have a little package in pip and I want to install it. Let's call it noty. The issue is that if I install it with 
`sudo pip3 install noty` 
the program will run but if I install it using 
`pip3 install noty`
every time I will try typing noty into the terminal it just won't work. Any solution? Thanks in advance. I am also including some lines of my setup.py file, if that somehow helps.

```
entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        noty=noty.noty:cli
    ''',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create a virtual environment (for this, I suggest `pew` https://github.com/berdario/pew) and to install the desired package in it. Entry points are supported in virtual environments.

A possible alternative is to rely on `pipx`:
https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx

Last but not least, you can install packages with pip in "user mode": the packages will be installed in your user directory (e.g. `pip install noty --user`). Unfortunately, nearly none of the "common distributions" supports entry points that way (because they are installed in "~/.local/bin") unless you add this folder to the PATH:

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

This line can be added to "~/.bash_profile" so it is automatically loaded on startup (and if you don't want to wait until the next startup, simply do `source ~/.bash_profile`).

Answer (score 1):

Sudo is needed, otherwise those directories (e.g. /usr/lib/python/site-packages/) are not writeable.